# DBUnit, use DTD with annotation configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, dbunit

I am having a problem with one of my dbUnit test that i am not able to solve. There is a data structure that has a parent-child relation defined by the jpa annotations:

```
/**
 * Parent account
 */
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "parentAccountId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Account parentAccount;

/**
 * Subordinated accounts
 */
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentAccount")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Account> childAccounts = new HashSet<Account>();
```

I have an abstract class that loads a dataset in the database before performing the junit test, the class has the following annotations:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup("classpath:db-test-script.xml")
@DatabaseTearDown(type=DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL, value = { "classpath:db-test-    script.xml" })
```

which works great but not for the classes that I mentioned before. The data structure in the dataset looks like this:

```
<referralAccount id="2" code="CODE2" />
<referralAccount id="1" code="CODE" parentAccountId="2"/>
```

But the problem that I find in the logs is the following:

**FlatXmlProducer:316 - Extra columns (parentAccountId) on line 2 for table Account (global line number is 5). Those columns will be ignored.
    Please add the extra columns to line 1, or use a DTD to make sure the value of those columns are populated or specify 'columnSensing=true' for your FlatXmlProducer.
    See FAQ for more details.**

The question is, is there a way to specify a dtd or the columnSensing by annotations? I don't want to implement a setUp method if I can avoid it, as the annotations seemed to be a clean an easy way to deal with this.

Thanks!

Comment: The DTD should be specified in the XML file, not in annotations. Or you could simply specify `parentAccountId="null"` for the first line, as the error message says. Or you could use [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/)

Comment: you mean adding a reference to it like __<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM "my-dataset.dtd">__ or embedding it inside the xml itself? (not sure if this is even possible)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using DBUnit 2.3.0 or higher you can use the ColumnSensing property as is described in [dbunit javadoc](http://www.dbunit.org/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/xml/FlatXmlDataSet.html):

> Beware that DbUnit may think a table misses some columns if the first
>   row of that table has one or more null values. You can do one of the
>   following things to avoid this:
>
> Since DBUnit 2.3.0 there is a functionality called "column sensing"
>   which basically reads in the whole XML into a buffer and dynamically
>   adds new columns as they appear. It can be used as demonstrated in the
>   following example:

```
  // since dbunit 2.4.7
   FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
   builder.setInputSource(new File("src/xml/flatXmlTableTest.xml"));
   builder.setColumnSensing(true);
   IDataSet dataSet = builder.build();

   // or dbunit release <= 2.4.6:
   boolean enableColumnSensing = true;
   IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(
            new File("src/xml/flatXmlTableTest.xml"), false, enableColumnSensing);
```

So if you are using spring, you can create a class such as:

```
public class ColumnDetectorXmlDataSetLoader extends FlatXmlDataSetLoader {
@Override
protected IDataSet createDataSet(Resource resource) throws Exception {
FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
builder.setColumnSensing(true);
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
try {
return builder.build(inputStream);
} finally {
inputStream.close();
}
}
}
```

and then in you junit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/spring-context.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup("my-dataset.xml")
@DatabaseTearDown("my-dataset.xml")
// Reference to the ColumnDetectorXmlDataSetLoader
@DbUnitConfiguration(dataSetLoader = ColumnDetectorXmlDataSetLoader.class)
public class MyTestTest {

}
```

In this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue times ago. There are 3 solutions, I applied the former:

1. In your Flatxml every first row should contains all the columns you are going to use/test for the given table. (I do not found any way to specify column sensing in spring+dbunit via annotation), in your case swap the rows.
2. using DTD (cannot remember why I discarded this option that time), you specify a DTD in the beginning of your dataset xml file ie: `<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM "dataset.dtd">` (see below for the format)
3. (Headache way) Define your own annotation or get rid of the annotations and fallback to the classic DbUnit/java where you have full control on things such as column sensing.

the dataset **DTD** has this format (example):

```
<!ELEMENT dataset (
    ACCOUNT*)>
<!ELEMENT ACCOUNT EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST ACCOUNT
    USER_ID CDATA #REQUIRED
    ACCOUNT_BALANCE CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

Answer (score 1):

with dbunit version 2.5.1 used this :

```
InputStream inputStream = ClassNameTest.class.getResourceAsStream(name);
assertNotNull("file " + name + " not found in classpath", inputStream);
FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
builder.setColumnSensing(true);
return builder.build(inputStream);
```